# Zend Framework 2: Populate ajax table (DataTable)

Tags: ajax, zend-framework2

Below is snippet of table-ajax.js file from DataTable module. 
My question is what will be Ajax url instead of **table_ajax.php** if I use  IndexAction{} in my Controller. I want to display data from database.

```
    var handleRecords = function () {

    var grid = new Datatable();

    grid.init({
        src: $("#datatable_ajax"),
        onSuccess: function (grid) {
        },
        onError: function (grid) {
        },
        onDataLoad: function(grid) {
        },
        loadingMessage: 'Loading...',
        dataTable: { 

            "bStateSave": true, // save datatable state(pagination, sort, etc) in cookie.

            "lengthMenu": [
                [10, 20, 50, 100, 150, -1],
                [10, 20, 50, 100, 150, "All"] // change per page values here
            ],
            "pageLength": 10, // default record count per page
            "ajax": {
                "url": "table_ajax.php", // ajax source
            },
            "order": [
                [1, "asc"]
            ]// set first column as a default sort by asc
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you'll need to add a strategy to your viewmanager so you can return json. This is done within your module.config like so:

```
'view_manager' => array(
...
   'strategies' => array(
       'ViewJsonStrategy'
   ),
...
),
```

I'll just assume you have this DataTableModule imported via your Autoloader. So you can extend or implement the "table_ajax.php" within your controller and override/add a return value as a zf2 JsonModel.

> In your Action within your Controller that extends/implements ajax_table.php

```
...
return new JsonModel($whateverTheResultIs);
...
```

Now that you have a controller that returns your JSON you'll require to set up a route. This is pretty straight forward it only links to your controller action and since you defined a strategy in your Viewmanager ZF2 does the rest of the pesky ajax stuff for you.

Edit: Rather then extending the table_ajax.php in your controller it probably is a good idea to write a Service which retrieves the information from table_ajax.php.